# Is there a DataWeave 1.0 "for" operator?

Tags: mule, dataweave

I would like to create as many elements as a count variable specifies, for example:

There is a table that has information about supported equipment

```sql
select port_count 
from equipment
where id=#[flowVars.equipmentId]
```

And I've to generate a message that another system out of my control interprets and executes:

```xml
<dw:transform-message doc:name="Get value">
    <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
  "actions": {
    (for 1..flowVars.port_count map {
      "action": {
        "type": "add_port",
        "id": $$
      }
    })
  }
}]]></dw:set-payload>
</dw:transform-message>
```

Desired result:

```
{
  "actions": {
    "action": {
        "type": "add_port",
        "id": 1
    },
    "action": {
        "type": "add_port",
        "id": 2
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DataWeave has no concept of for because it is a functional language. Still you can what you want by using a range instead:

```
%dw 1.0
%var port_count=3
%output application/json
---
{
  actions: 
    (((1 to port_count) when port_count > 0 otherwise []) map
      action: {
        "type": "add_port",
        "id": $
      }
    )  reduce ($$ ++ $)
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "actions": {
    "action": {
      "type": "add_port",
      "id": 1
    },
    "action": {
      "type": "add_port",
      "id": 2
    },
    "action": {
      "type": "add_port",
      "id": 3
    }
  }
}
```

Just change the port_count variable for the flowVar and you will be all set.

Removing the reduce() operator will return a list instead, which would make more sense to me.

Comment: Thank you @aled, that indeed works for what I asked, but I'm noticing that even if the count goes to 0 it creates 2 elements (1 and 0). Do you know how I could prevent the range from generating if the count is 0?

Comment: Good catch. A reverse range (1 to 0) is valid too in DataWeave. I updated the answer using the operator `max` to avoid that condition. You can use a function for better clarity.

Comment: Thank @aled. I've updated the answer to use the when/otherwise selector instead, this is because the max always generated at least one element

Comment: When port_count=0 the result is: {"actions": null }, is that the expected result?

Comment: Yes, that's what I would expect, you can then use a `default` if you wish to replace `null` with something else, but in my case there were other actions, so when the count is zero I don't want anything added to the object